# Update to drupal 8.7 caused paragraphs to display improperly

Tags: paragraphs, bootstrap-theme

I am using bootstrap paragraphs (BP) as part of my project.  When I updated to D8.7, the BPs that define layout (e.g. 2 column, accordion, etc.) stopped displaying.  I then tried a roll back to 8.6 but the problem remains.  Has anyone encountered this?  Any solution that you can think of?  Places to look for troubleshooting.

Comment: You could try to see if you can replicate your issue on a fresh D8.6 install, install the module and then update to D8.7. The results of this may provide clues. Did you run `/update.php`?

Comment: If you switch to Bartik theme, does the same issue persist?